# How to display current values in pie chart & bar chart labels, like in tooltips?

Tags: dc.js

Please see the image below. The pie chart only shows category 2011, 2012 & 2013. The row bar chart only shows Mr. A, Mr.B & Mr. C.

How can I edit my code below to make the labels display what is shown in the tooltips that are displayed on hover?

I want to display all labels like "2011: 80" instead of "2011" (using the selection to change the value).

Also "2012: 90" instead of "2012", and "2013: 80" instead of "2013".

The rest of charts should also **display the names with values**. How can I change the code to achieve this?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>dc.js - Removing Empty Bars</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dc-js/dc.js/develop/web-src/examples/header.js"></script>
  <p>Example demonstrating using a "<a href="https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups">Fake Group</a>" to remove
    the empty bars of an ordinal bar chart when their values drop to zero.</p>

  <p>(Note the use of <code><a href="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#elasticX">.elasticX(true)</a></code>
    to force calculation of the X domain each round.)</p>

<div id="chart-ring-year"></div>
<div id="chart-hist-spend"></div>
<div id="chart-row-spenders"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.1.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/4.1.1/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var yearRingChart   = new dc.PieChart("#chart-ring-year"),
    spendHistChart  = new dc.BarChart("#chart-hist-spend"),
    spenderRowChart = new dc.RowChart("#chart-row-spenders");

// use static or load via d3.csv("spendData.csv").then(function(spendData) {/* do stuff */});
var spendData = [
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$40', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$10', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$40', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$70', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$20', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$50', Year: 2013},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$30', Year: 2013}
];

// normalize/parse data
spendData.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Spent = d.Spent.match(/\d+/);
});

function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value != 0;
            });
        }
    };
}

// set crossfilter
var ndx = crossfilter(spendData),
    yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;}),
    spendDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return Math.floor(d.Spent/10);}),
    nameDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Name;}),
    spendPerYear = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendPerName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendHist    = spendDim.group().reduceCount(),
    nonEmptyHist = remove_empty_bins(spendHist)

yearRingChart
    .width(200).height(200)
    .dimension(yearDim)
    .group(spendPerYear)
    .innerRadius(50);

spendHistChart
    .width(300).height(200)
    .dimension(spendDim)
    .group(nonEmptyHist)
    .x(d3.scaleBand())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true);

spendHistChart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d*10}); // convert back to base unit
spendHistChart.yAxis().ticks(2);

spenderRowChart
    .width(350).height(200)
    .dimension(nameDim)
    .group(spendPerName)
    .elasticX(true);

dc.renderAll();

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip text is controlled by [.title()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#title__anchor), because `title` is the SVG tag for tooltips, and the label is controlled by [.label()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#label__anchor).

Pass each one of these a function that takes the data `{key, value}` and returns the text you want.

The default tooltip/title function is `d => d.key + ': ' + d.value`.

A lazy way to copy the title function to the label is

```
yearRingChart
    .label(yearRingChart.title())
```

Or, for more control, define it yourself:

```
    .label(d => d.key + ': ' + d.value)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>dc.js - Removing Empty Bars</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dc-js/dc.js/develop/web-src/examples/header.js"></script>

<div id="chart-ring-year"></div>
<div id="chart-hist-spend"></div>
<div id="chart-row-spenders"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.1.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/4.1.1/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var yearRingChart   = new dc.PieChart("#chart-ring-year"),
    spendHistChart  = new dc.BarChart("#chart-hist-spend"),
    spenderRowChart = new dc.RowChart("#chart-row-spenders");

// use static or load via d3.csv("spendData.csv").then(function(spendData) {/* do stuff */});
var spendData = [
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$40', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$10', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$40', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$70', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$20', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$50', Year: 2013},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$30', Year: 2013}
];

// normalize/parse data
spendData.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Spent = d.Spent.match(/\d+/);
});

function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value != 0;
            });
        }
    };
}

// set crossfilter
var ndx = crossfilter(spendData),
    yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;}),
    spendDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return Math.floor(d.Spent/10);}),
    nameDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Name;}),
    spendPerYear = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendPerName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendHist    = spendDim.group().reduceCount(),
    nonEmptyHist = remove_empty_bins(spendHist)


yearRingChart
    .width(200).height(200)
    .ordinalColors(d3.schemeCategory10)
    .label(yearRingChart.title())
    .dimension(yearDim)
    .group(spendPerYear)
    .innerRadius(50);

spendHistChart
    .width(300).height(200)
    .ordinalColors(d3.schemeCategory10)
//        .label(spendHistChart.title())
    .dimension(spendDim)
    .group(nonEmptyHist)
    .x(d3.scaleBand())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true);

spendHistChart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d*10}); // convert back to base unit
spendHistChart.yAxis().ticks(2);

spenderRowChart
    .width(350).height(200)
    .ordinalColors(d3.schemeCategory10)
    .label(d => d.key + ': ' + d.value)
    .dimension(nameDim)
    .group(spendPerName)
    .elasticX(true);

dc.renderAll();

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```